# Two domains, one site - what's the best way to set this up?

Tags: redirects, domains

I'm setting up a site, say mysite.com. I've also bought mysite.net.

What's the best way to mange this so that regardless which the user types, they end up on mysite.com?

Also, what are the implications for SERPS, if any? Is it as simple as putting a small redirect asp file on the mysite.net directory like:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://www.mysite.com/"
%>
```

Any downsides to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You definitely want to do a 301 redirect. This makes sure the search engines know the main URL is the only URL you want them to use. This is important, not only for usability's sake but ensures that you won't have duplicate content issues by having the same content on two different URLs.

Since it sounds like your site is new there won't be any other ramifications to this. If your site was older doing this would also benefit you by making sure any links you got to your secondary URL would be transferred over to the primary domain which would be a positive thing for SEO.